# Adding the host to links in ActionMailer by calling object instead of full route name

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, email, ruby-on-rails-3.2, actionmailer

I'm working on a Rails 3.2.14 app and I would like to add links to pages inside my application.

I have setup in my `config/environments/*.rb` files

```
config.action_mailer.default_url_options = { :host => 'example.com' }
```

I've been able to add links to my email templates by using things like

```
<%= link_to "Group name", group_url(@group) %>
```

But I was wondering if there was a way to do provide an option so I can call

```
<%= link_to "Group name", @group, ... %>
```

like I do in my view templates. What option would add so that ActionMailer would be able to discern the host and add it to the url that is being used as the `href`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm going to use the `polymorphic_url` method mentioned in these links http://api.rubyonrails.org/v3.2.14/files/actionpack/lib/action_dispatch/routing/polymorphic_routes_rb.html and  http://rails-bestpractices.com/posts/55-generate-polymorphic-url

Answer (score 0):

As you may know `link_to(name = nil, options = nil, html_options = nil, &block)` receives an options hash in the second argument (the "href").

If you see the source code:

```
def link_to(name = nil, options = nil, html_options = nil, &block)
  html_options, options = options, name if block_given?
  options ||= {}

  html_options = convert_options_to_data_attributes(options, html_options)

  url = url_for(options)
  html_options['href'] ||= url

  content_tag(:a, name || url, html_options, &block)
end
```

Those options are passed to `url_for` method. In docs:

> Note that by default :only_path is true so you’ll get the relative
>   “/controller/action” instead of the fully qualified URL like
>   “example.com/controller/action”.

So, you can:

```
<%= link_to "Group name", path: @group, only_path: false, ... %>
```

But this is a little bit more verbose than using the `_url` helper method. In resume, the answer is: there is no way to simply use `@group` in the `link_to` helper method..

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. I think I found a simpler solution by looking through the rails docs related to the things you were mentioning.